# parquet-tools cannot read zstd files but can read gzip?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, parquet-mr

I installed the latest version of `parquet-tools` from `apache-mr` with version `parquet-tools-1.8.2.jar`.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = GET_CLIENT() # redacted
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=["a","b","c"])
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> filebuf = BytesIO()
>>> df.to_parquet(filebuf, compression="zstd") # Change this to gzip and it works!
>>> client.put_object(Bucket="foo", Key="bar/example.zstd.parquet", Body=filebuf.getvalue())
```

I `aws s3 cp`'d the parquet file and tried to run `parquet-tools head` on it, but got:

```
$ parquet-tools head example.zstd.parquet
Could not read footer: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, doing the same command on a gzip-compressed file gives me:

```
$ parquet-tools head example.gzip.parquet
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Is this a bug with zstd compression or parquet-tools? Or did I not read the fineprint somewhere?

*NOTE: My `parquet-tools` is aliased to `java -jar .../parquet-tools-1.8.2.jar`*